# is it possible to configure PHP to use virtualhost

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2

Actually, I downloaded PHP7.2.7 safe thread from PHP's website(php.net) and I don't know if it is possible I can configure PHP to setup a virtualhost like we can do using XAMPP

Comment: i don't it is possible to do that in php

Comment: PHP is nothing to do with virtualhost and it is a part of webserver you are using.If apache then you can create virtualhost at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in web server, but is has limited capability.  It does not provide all the configuration options a complete web server does.  It does not do VirtualHost.

If you need VirtualHost, you will have to include it as a module inside Apache (or other web server).  The module will be global.  If your pages in a VirtualHost do not need PHP, PHP remains dormant and does nothing.

Comment: Since built-in PHP webserver is intended for development, it should run on localhost. All the 127.0.0.0/12 adresses are reserved for loopback, we can add `127.0.0.2 localhost2` into vhosts and run another instance of webserver to listen on its own IP as a separate process having its own configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below configuration:

1) Entry in hosts file as below

```
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

2) Set virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/public_html"
    ServerAlias quickstart.com
    <Directory "/var/www/example/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't a web server, you need to create a VirtualHost in Apache. If you're using Linux, open up `httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
and enter the following lines.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to restart your web server/apache in order to these changes to work.